# Possible to autofill text fields for a web-embedded internet speed test?

Tags: javascript, iframe, autofill, speed-test

OpenSpeedTest provides HTML5 code to embed a speed test widget in your webpage. I have implemented this for my website, however there is no API to fetch the results and autofill my text fields. Obviously I also cannot access a cross-origin frame using Javascript, so I don't know what to do. Speedtest Ookla no longer has an accessible API to do this, so I'm not sure what other options I have here.

```
<script>
    function getSpeedTestResults() {
        // Attempt to access the iframe content
        let iframe = document.getElementById('speedtest');
        let iframeContent = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        // Attempt to access the results inside the iframe (this will likely be blocked)
                let downloadSpeed = iframeContent.getElementById('downResult').textContent;
        let uploadSpeed = iframeContent.getElementById('upRestxt').textContent;
        let ping = iframeContent.getElementById('pingResult').textContent;

        // Set the values in your fields
        document.getElementById('download').value = downloadSpeed;
        document.getElementById('upload').value = uploadSpeed;
        document.getElementById('ping').value = ping;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I suppose you got two options to chose from: A) find yourself another speed test provider, that has an API that allows you to access the results, or B) ask the user to type their result from the iframe widget into your form fields themselves, before they submit ... Since you didn't loose a single word about what the eventual _purpose_ of this is - or how many users need to execute this, and how many times/in what frequency - of course I can't say, how "workable" option B) would be.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, that's what I figured. The purpose is for https://thewirednomad.com/submit.html. I think it would be fine to just have them manually enter because it's not something a user has to do more than once in any given time. Just wanted to be fancy and make it a more seamless experience.

Comment: you can use a different speed test tool that provides an API. For example, SpeedOf.Me has an API that allows you to fetch speed test results programmatically. You could use this API to retrieve the results and autofill your text fields.

Comment: @AfzalK. Nice! I know about speedof.me but didn't realize they have an API.